# How to add two icon sin trailing of ListTile using Column

Tags: flutter, icons, listtile

I am trying to add two icon in trailing of ListTile, and i want then i column but can't fix the render flow error, please help how to do this.

here is the code

```
Widget buildBook(Book book) =>Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10),
                  ),),
    child:ListTile(
        trailing:SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: Column(  //here i am doing
            children: [
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit,color: HexColor("#7367f0"),),
                onPressed: (){
              _getVariantRowInfo(book.id, book.author, book.title);
                },),
                 IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: HexColor("#7367f0"),),
                onPressed: (){
              _getVariantRowInfo(book.id, book.author, book.title);
                 
              
                },),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 15, 0),
          child: Text("  Discounted Price:  90",),
        ),
        horizontalTitleGap: 10,
        subtitle:Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
              Text("  "+book.author,style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 15),),
              Text("  "+book.title,style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 15),),
              SizedBox(height: 10,)
            ],
           
          ), 
      ));
```

here is the snap

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you

```
   Card(
            color: Colors.cyan[50],
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Your Title'),
              subtitle: Text('Your Sub Title'),
              trailing: Column(
                children: [
                    InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //call your onpressed function here
                      print('Button Pressed');
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //call your onpressed function here
                      print('Button Pressed');
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen->  [image]

Comment: hey!  ```icon``` are working fine but i'm using ```IconButton``` that's causes this issue

Comment: i want to perform actions on onclick on icon that's why i'm using iconbutton, please let me know if u can fix it.

Comment: @TimeToCode check my updated answer use Inkwell widget instead of IconButton

Comment: ohh mannn! God Bless u moreee! thankyou so much!

Comment: @TimeToCode Glad to help you , Enjoy your ride with flutter

Comment: does only work with two inkwell... a third one would give error.

Comment: @Defarine Its working well on my side, If this is not working on your machine use `GestureDetector`  [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) instead of `InkWell`

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil its not work for more 3 items

Comment: @alhelal yes it will work 3 item as well please try to give Height of card or wrap trailing column inside Container or Sizedbox and give it to Height or you don’t use both Container or SizedBox Wrap Column inside SingleChildScrollView